# Given a ContainerBuilder, can I register a missing dependency handler?

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to make a method with the following signature:

```cs
void Chain(ContainerBuilder builder, IServiceProvider fallbackServiceProvider)
{
   // ...
}
```

The idea is that `Chain` can be used as follows:

```cs
IServiceProvider fallbackProvider = someExternalProvider;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Custom registration might happen before and/or after the call to Chain
builder.Register<MyCustomService>().As<IMyCustomService>();
builder.Register<MyExternalServiceReplacement>.As<IExternalService>();

Chain(builder, someExternalProvider);

IContainer container = builder.Build();

// customService should be a MyCustomService
var customService = container.Resolve<IMyCustomService>();

// replacedService should be overridden by MyExternalServiceReplacement
// even though an IExternalService also exists in someExternalProvider
var replacedService = container.Resolve<IExternalService>();

// nonReplacedService should come from someExternalProvider since
// no IExternalService2 was registered with the ContainerBuilder
var nonReplacedService = container.Resolve<IExternalService2>();
```

Ideally there would be some type of missing dependency handler that I could register with the ContainerBuilder.

Alternatively, I could probably get by with some way to register a component that could intercept every call to `Resolve*`, `TryResolve*`, etc... This would also need to intercept the dependency resolution for constructor injection.

Unfortunately, there is no way to query the IServiceProvider to get every service it provides. I can only call into the `object IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)` method of the `fallbackServicProvider`.

Comment: You need to implement your own `IRegistrationSource`, here is article containing a sample one: http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/

Comment: Hello @halter73, can you provide me a demo for multiple chat rooms using signalR. I want to implement chat server like chat.stackoverflow.com. Please provide any good solutions and link to implement chat server.

Comment: my email id is: moaman@88gmail.com. if u have any demo please send me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a custom `IRegistrationSource` implementation: when the container needs to provide a service, it queries the registered registration sources to get any available implementations.

So inside the registeration source you can ask your `IServiceProvider` to give you a fallback implementation for a given type.

Here is a good article intoroducing the whole registration source in Autofac: [Declarative Context Adapters in Autofac 2](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/)

Based on that I've knocked together a prototype `IRegistrationSource` implementation (so **it is not fully tested nor production ready**, but it was working with your sample scenario) what you can build on:

```cs
public class MyRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public MyRegistrationSource(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service,
        Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        // there are other registration exists in the container
        if (registrationAccessor(service).Any())
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();

        var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (swt == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();

        // try to get an instance from the IServiceProvider
        var instance = serviceProvider.GetService(swt.ServiceType);
        if (instance == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();

        // register the instance in the container
        return new[]
            {
                RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(swt.ServiceType, 
                    (c, p) => instance)
                    .CreateRegistration()
            };
    }
    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents { get { return false; } }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```cs
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

 // Custom registration might happen before and/or after the call to Chain
 builder.RegisterType<MyCustomService>().As<IMyCustomService>();
 builder.RegisterType<MyExternalServiceReplacement>().As<IExternalService>();

 //Chain(builder, someExternalProvider);
 builder.RegisterSource(new MyRegistrationSource(new ServiceProvider()));

 IContainer container = builder.Build();
```