# Autofac - Get registered GenericDecorators for Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac

I use Autofac version 5.2.0 and I have multiple `Decorators`
(https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html)

I register them like so:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(QueryHandlerExceptionDecorator<,>),
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
```

This works perfectly fine.

The registration itself happens dynamically, depending on a configuration file or an `Action<ContainerBuilder>` statement.

In my unit tests I would like to do something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(containberBuilder.IsGenericDecoratorRegistered(
    typeof(QueryHandlerExceptionDecorator<,>)));
```

But neither the `ContainerBuilder` class nor the `IContainer` implementation after calling `containerBuilder.Build();` offer any method or property to get decorator registrations.

I came across the following article with a custom registration source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345045/1099519, but even there I could not find a way to get a list of registered decorators.

I could of course unit test some functionality the specific decorator offers when I get an instance that is decorated and assume that it is registered by that, but that's not the way I want to do that.

Comment: Instead of unit testing whether the decorator is *registered*, I'd rather verify whether the decorator is *applied*. Or, when possible, verify the existence of the decorator's behavior.

Comment: What are you trying to test ? Is it the `RegisterGenericDecorator` method ? Instead of trying to rely on internal *Autofac* mechanism, I would resolve a decorated component dedicated for this test and check if the decorator is applied by using the component

Comment: I want to unit test my logic, if certain decorators were registered. So if there is a way to make sure they were registered, it would be great, rather than testing the actual behavior. Like in the ServiceCollector to iterate all services, i'd like to do the same with decorators.

Answer (score 0):

As I could not figure out a proper solution to find out directly which decorators are configured, I ended up with the solution of my on "registrar":

```
public interface IDecoratorRegistrar
{
    void RegisterGenericDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType);
    void RegisterGenericDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType);
    void RegisterDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType);
    void RegisterDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType, Func<IDecoratorContext, bool>? condition);
}
```

This is the actual implementation for Autofac registrations:

```
public class DecoratorRegistrar : IDecoratorRegistrar
{
    public void RegisterGenericDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)
    {
        RegisterGenericDecorator(builder, decoratorType, serviceType, null);
    }
    public void RegisterGenericDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType, Func<IDecoratorContext, bool>? condition)
    {
        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(decoratorType, serviceType, condition);
    }
    public void RegisterDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)
    {
        RegisterDecorator(builder, decoratorType, serviceType, null);
    }
    public void RegisterDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType, Func<IDecoratorContext, bool>? condition)
    {
        builder.RegisterDecorator(decoratorType, serviceType, condition);
    }
}
```

The implementation for unit tests is:

```
public class MockDecoratorRegistrar : IDecoratorRegistrar
{
    public IList<(Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)> Decorators { get; } = new List<(Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)>();
    public IList<(Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)> GenericDecorators { get; } = new List<(Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)>();

    public void RegisterDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)
    {
        Decorators.Add((decoratorType, serviceType));
    }

    public void RegisterDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType, Func<IDecoratorContext, bool>? condition)
    {
        Decorators.Add((decoratorType, serviceType));
    }

    public void RegisterGenericDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType)
    {
        GenericDecorators.Add((decoratorType, serviceType));
    }

    public void RegisterGenericDecorator(ContainerBuilder builder, Type decoratorType, Type serviceType, Func<IDecoratorContext, bool>? condition)
    {
        GenericDecorators.Add((decoratorType, serviceType));
    }
}
```

To register a decorator I now call:

```
decoratorRegistrar.RegisterGenericDecorator(containerBuilder, typeof(ActionCommandHandlerExceptionDecorator<>), typeof(IActionCommandHandler<>));
```

`decoratorRegistrar` is either an instance of `DecoratorRegistrar` or `MockDecoratorRegistrar` in unit tests.

In my unit tests I can now easily check the registrations by calling:

```
mockDecoratorRegistrar.GenericDecorators.Should().Contain(item => item.decoratorType == expectedType);
```

This abstraction solves my actual issue. 
Still: If someone has a solution accessing Decorator registrations directly from Autofac, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the decorators for a given service using the `IComponentRegistry.DecoratorsFor` method available from the `ComponentRegistry` property of the built container.

You can pass that method an instance of `TypedService` to get the decorator registrations, like so:

```cs
var decorators = container.ComponentRegistry.DecoratorsFor(new TypedService(typeof(IDecoratedService)));
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution and it did work for non-generic decorators, but not for generic ones. I tried like this: var decorators = container.ComponentRegistry.DecoratorsFor(new TypedService(typeof(IActionCommandHandler<>)));

Comment: That's more tricky...Autofac never looks up decorators by the open generic service, it only looks them up by the closed generic. For your tests is it sufficient to check you can get decorators for `IActionCommandHandler<AnActualType>`?

Comment: Calling `container.ComponentRegistry.DecoratorsFor(new TypedService(typeof(IActionCommandHandler<SampleActionCommand>)));` in fact worked and `SampleActionCommand` doesn't need to be registered. Thank you. Still the solution is not ideal in my scenario, so i stick with the "answer" I posted. Maybe it could be an enhancement in a future version to have the possibility to iterate all registered decorators.